# Why LSTM models do not require labels for each step?

Tags: deep-learning, lstm

For time related problems like, for example, stock prediction:

Let's say we have 300 days of data, 10 features, and one target: the price.

Why, for the training, we only need the price of the 300th day?
I know this is the way LSTM models work, but wouldn't it be useful to take into account the price of the 299 other days for the model?

Answer (score 0):

**Time-series analysis has two main goals:**

- To identifying the nature of the phenomenon represented by the sequence of observations, and
- To forecast (predicting future values in time for a variable).

**NOTE: In this respect, models try to get pattern using historical values. Do not confuse here between forecasting (predicting future values) and prediction.**

For time-series prediction(forecasting) problems, **the models ( ARIMA, LSTM) try to extract trend, seasonality, and residual from the list of historical values** e.g. price from 300 historical dates or time. Therefore, there is no need to look for dependent variables here.
We must be clear, **the time series forecasting algorithm extrapolate historical trend to near and far future.** **They do not predict target variable based on dependent variables.** This is the main reason you will see time-series models only work with single variable who's historical data-points become input and future data points become target.

**Reference:**

1. http://www.statsoft.com/Textbook/Time-Series-Analysis

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The difference is that, most of the time, in time series, we only use the price and the date as variables. Here, there are a lot of features. So, I was wondering if I should incorporate the labels of the past days, or only the labels of the last day? 

For example, if I want to predict a temperature, and I have 10 features, and seven days. Should I use the temperature of the six first days in my LSTM model, or only the seventh day temperature as label??

Comment: And then, we can say that here, it’s not a time series problem, but just a prediction based on several days of data for each point.

Comment: No, this is a wrong conclusion. Time-series models use historical data points as dependent to predict future points ( forecast).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are confused about what the difference between a feature and a label is.

Your label is the 'gold' outcome that you are trying to predict. In stock prediction, this is often a single number, i.e. some form of regression. For a given time series you are trying to predict the price at a future point in time.

What you are suggesting is very well possible, and basically how (linear) regression works: given 300 data points, make a function that fits the data. Then get the value from the function from a given `x`. LSTMs and other architectures are of course more complex, but the idea is similar.

You could, for instance, feed the prices of each time stamp as a feature to the LSTM. It should be a powerful predictor. The neural network will try to figure out which features are important at what stage in time.

Comment: Hello,
I'm totally aware of the difference between feature and label. What I'm saying is that, in a classic model, you have, say, 10 features, and one label. Here, I have these 10 features for 7 successive days. Thus, I use a LSTM to use this additional strength. However, I also have the labels for everyday, but, with a classic LSTM, Y is only the last day labels. So, my question was:

If I want to use Y of the other 6 days, may I:
1) Do as you suggest and include these 6 days labels in my features
2) Or, there is a model that can take it differently.

Comment: Yes, you can add it as a feature for the previous days.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So, that's the only way to use it?

Comment: You can also build a simple regression model next to the RNN, and in some way concatenate its output (average, max pool, ...)